# Numerical Method for solving Newtonian Equation of Motion for Particle experiencing drag in fluid flow

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, projectile, drag

Currently, I have a fluid solver that can calculate the lift and drag forces acting on a body on a per timestep basis. This means that I have data regarding the hydrodynamic forces only for the current timestep and times before that.

To simulate the sedimentation of a particle in a fluid, we were hoping to solve the following equation.

$$m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = mg - \text{Buoyant Force} + \text{Drag Force}$$

So the algorithm is as follows:-

1. Calculate the forces acting on the body in the current timestep.
2. Use the forces and the current position to calculate the new value of the position by the use of the above equation and a particular method.

While discretizing the equation for the forward Euler method, we just need to know the forces of the current time step and calculate the new value of the position. But higher order methods which are more accurate, like Runge-Kutta, require values from forward time steps.

Regarding all of this I have the following questions.

1. Is there a flaw in my approach to the entire problem and am I confusing the difference between discretizing the equation and solving it? Should the choice of using methods such as Runge-Kutta or Euler only come in when there is an ODE to solve? And should I, in this case, go along with discretizing the equation with something like Finite Difference?
2. If methods like RK4 or Euler can be used, then how does one do so when the values needed currently are for a future timestep (in the case of RK4). Or is there a flaw in my understanding of the algorithm and am I missing something there as well?
3. What is, in essence, the difference between discretizing an ODE using methods like finite difference or central difference or solving it using Runge-Kutta or Euler.

Comment: Your differential equation is ODE not PDE

Comment: I think you should dedicate some time to study the RK4 algorithm. I would never say that it uses future time steps.

Comment: @Eli edited the question

Comment: Your starting equation is dimensionally inconsistent.  Vertical acceleration is not equal to force.

Comment: @DavidWhite Edited, surprised I missed that

Comment: @Areen are you sure that you should be adding the drag force to your equation.  That equation implies that an object is falling through a buoyant liquid.  If that is the case, the drag force is in the same direction as the buoyant force.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, drag for the particle under the motion of gravity will be in the same direction as buoyancy and opposite that of weight. But I've left the sign of the drag force up to the solver to decide. Hence the plus sign. The solver will automatically adjust the sign depending on the direction of drag and the given sign convention.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 For the case of an ODE with the following formulation $y' = f(t,y)$ the approximation for $y_{n+1}$ includes terms such as $f(t_n + h,h*k1)$ which for me would involve calculating forces (or any other value) in a physics simulation of a future time step (namely, $t_n+h$). Is my understanding here wrong in some way? Would be happy if you could clear it up.

Comment: $y_{n+1}$ is in the future of $y_{n}$, true, but it depends on quantities at time $t_n$. In RK methods, the passage from quantities at $t_n$ to $t_{n+1}$ si performed through some intermediate steps, where each step depends on its "past" only. No "future" data is an independent variable.

Comment: @Areen, why you choose the positive $y$ direction downward? And drag force is always negative in any positive direction you choose.